# request.user always returns Anonymous user, even though request.META gives proper token when decoded in JWT it gives user_id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]
```

views.py

```
def google_login_view(request):
    if not request.user.email:
        return HttpResponse("An email is required to login.", status=400)
    email_from_google = request.user.email
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email_from_google, is_active=True)
        user_details = UserDetails.objects.get(email=email_from_google, is_active=True)
    except (User.DoesNotExist, UserDetails.DoesNotExist):
        return HttpResponse("User not found. Please register.", status=404)

    #  generate_token_pair is defined in tokens.py
    access_token, refresh_token, access_token_exp, refresh_token_exp = generate_token_pair(user)

    current_time = datetime.now()
    access_token_expiration_timestamp = access_token_exp.timestamp()
    access_token_expiration_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(access_token_expiration_timestamp)

    # Check if the access token has expired
    if access_token_expiration_datetime < current_time:

        # Check if the refresh token is still valid
        if refresh_token_exp >= current_time:

            with transaction.atomic():
                new_access_token, _, new_access_token_exp, _ = generate_token_pair(user)
                user.access_token = new_access_token
                user.save()

            # Log the user back in with the new access token
            login(request, user, backend='allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.backends.GoogleOAuth2')

            redirect_url = f"{settings.FRONTEND_REDIRECT_URL}?access_token={new_access_token}"
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            logout(request)  # Ensure the user is logged out
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    else:
        login(request, user, backend='allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.backends.GoogleOAuth2')
        redirect_url = f"{settings.FRONTEND_REDIRECT_URL}?access_token={access_token}"
        return redirect(redirect_url)


@authentication_classes([JSONWebTokenAuthentication])
@api_view(['POST'])
def send_client_feedback_email(request, project_id):
    try:
        pass
```

I have above setup Now when I Add PDB set trace in google login view I get a request.user of current logged in user.

Now when I try to use my POST METHOD and when I add request.user It returns Anonymous User.

In request.META I get User
header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
(Pdb) header_token
'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJleHAiOjE3MDY2OTExNDcsImlhdCI6MTcwNjY3Njc0N30.Wis2ro-_JvDeQB9eQERYF6K8UwuDnmTur2qtzyFvHQk'
(Pdb) print (request.user)
AnonymousUser

when I try to decode it I get correct {
"user_id": 2,
"exp": 1706691147,
"iat": 1706676747
}

So what is the issue and why am I getting a Anonymous user when using permission classes, I have tried Session, Token @login_required LoginMixedIn everything and it always returns as Anonymous User